# Best-case scenario for saving models files in Django project

Tags: python, django

I have a question about good practice for saving images in Django project.
Let's say we have two apps inside Django project *appOne* and *appTwo*.

Should I save my images for every app to the same root folder or every app should have a separate folder for images?

And is there a benefit if we create a folder for images for every model inside an app (if that model saves images).

I know that there's not one correct answer but there is always most useful case scenario in the long run.

p.s. I came from asp.net world and I fall in love with Django and Python

Comment: I'm not sure an out of the box Django project allows you to have multiple `MEDIA_ROOT`'s if that's what you're asking.

Comment: On image field I can put custom path and I am not sure what is best practice for that scenario:
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='api/books/author_pics/', null=True, blank=True)